# If conditions not being meet in android studios

Tags: java, android, if-statement

When the Update button is clicked the Toast message only shows the maintenance need even if the conditions are met. Not sure what the correct syntax is for getting the conditions of work.

```
    btnUpdateTractor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     // Update Button
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            dbHandler.updateTractor(tractor, tractorEdit.getText().toString(), hoursEdit.getText().toString(), oilEdit.getText().toString(), fuelEdit.getText().toString());


            if (hoursEdit.getText().toString().matches("[0000-9999]") && oilEdit.getText().toString().equals("Good") && fuelEdit.getText().toString().matches("[1500-3000]")) {

                // To update the tractor //

                Toast.makeText(user.this, "Tractor Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(user.this, user.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else if (hoursEdit.getText().toString().matches("[0000-9999]") && oilEdit.getText().toString().equals("Low") && fuelEdit.getText().toString().matches("[500-1000]")) {

                // If the tractor needs fuel and oil message appears //

                Toast.makeText(user.this, "Add Oil and Fuel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(user.this, user.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {

                // If none of the Editboxes match the conditions maintenance should be called //

                Toast.makeText(user.this, "Call Maintenance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

If have tried using .getText().toString.eqauls("1500-3000") and .getText().toString.matches("[1500-3000]")

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: So using getText().toString().matches"\\d\\d\\d\\d" works and meets the conditions thank you